# Youtube Full Screen Problem

Tags: flash, youtube, fullscreen

there is something wrong with my Youtube so my flash player, when i make it fullscreen, the margins of the player (pause, volume etc.) doesn't dissappear and it's a bit annoying, any solutions?? (using chrome 64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a solution to your problems with YouTube via a browser + flash, but [Minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) will allow you to play YouTube videos fullscreen without the issues you noted, and probably smoother as well.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minitube
```

You might try using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/) or chromium + pepperflashplugin-nonfree if you want to use YouTube in a browser.

Comment: forgot to tell i'm already using google chrome :D minitube has no function for me because i like using youtube with g+

Comment: i don't believe i forgot installing pepperflash in my fresh install, usually it's one of the first things to do in a fresh os install, thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry that didn't help, I hadn't considered users who are using YouTube with G+. You might consider contacting the Minitube developer Ferramosca Roberto and see if he can add the features you need. BTW, you don't need pepperflash with Chrome, only Chromium.